# How to use oracle utl_raw in android/java?

Tags: java, android, oracle

My android APP needs to sign in with PL-SQL database, and the user password is encrypted with

```
l_password := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(input_string => p_password || substr(l_salt,10,13) || p_username ||
substr(l_salt, 4,10)));
```

So now I need to compare in the app (case of offline login) for the password.
I did searched for an Oracle lib, but no luck so far.

Is there an Oracle lib with utl_raw? Or any other work around to verify this password in Android/Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any library. Raw in java is represented by bytes[]. 
Check out my example.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, Exception {
        Connection con = ConnectionDefinition.getOracleConnection(); //my oracle connection
        PreparedStatement pr = con.prepareStatement("select  utl_raw.cast_to_raw(dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(input_string =>'password')) from dual");
        ResultSet rs = pr.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        byte[] raw = rs.getBytes(1);
        String str = new String(raw);
        System.err.println(str);        

        //Generate MD5 Java
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update("password".getBytes());        
        byte byteData[] = md.digest();
        System.err.println(new String(byteData));        
        rs.close();
        pr.close();
        con.close();        
    }
```

Comment: I'm probably doing somethig wrong. So I have this "70C9391797C228F0795F98CF1059C956" password from the database and the user enters "dia.38X8MILTONINIP6Z", use //Generate MD5 Java didnt worked

Comment: Ok, salt in java and in oracle has to be the same. In you sql example md5 is calculated on string conncatenation `p_password || substr(l_salt,10,13)||p_username ||substr(l_salt, 4,10))`

Comment: oracle substr and java subString work in different way.
substr(start_position,length) , subString(start_position, end_position)  where length It is the number of characters to extract.

Comment: The substr method, that was it, MD5 with the right string works. Thanks Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz! ^^